# Partial raster reclassify in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, reclassify

I have a CHM model (raster) with values `-10` up `100`.

I need to reclassify values as:

- `value < 0` => `0`
- `0 < value < 50` => the same value
- `value > 50` => `0`

I tried so many tools, but I cannot find the correct way. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try Raster Calculator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Raster Calculator` with the following formula:

```
(("RasterFile@1" >  0) AND ("RasterFile@1" < 50)) * "RasterFile@1"
```

The above expression will produce a raster data with pixel values of more than Zero and less than 50 as they are (No change in pixel values). Other pixel values will be Zeros.

You need to replace `RasterFile` in the expression above with the correct name of the raster data that you have in the Raster Calculator.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly!